# Windows forms application generate another name

Tags: c#

```
namespace GenerateApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] name = new string[4];            

        public Form1()
        {                
            InitializeComponent();
            name[0] = textBox2.Text;
            name[1] = textBox3.Text;
            name[2] = textBox5.Text;
            name[3] = textBox6.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {


            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

Ok first of all I must mention that i'm at the very beginning with programming and i'm trying to do something in my eyes quite simple but doesn't work and I need your help. I want every time that i click on a button, in my current textboxes to be generated another names. Example textbox2.Text to be textbox3.Text, textbox3.Text to be textbox5.Text and so on till it repeats. Can someone tell me a method of how to do it? I would gladly appreciate it

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is the problem to iterate controls in loop? Put them into array first `var textBoxes = new[] { textBox2, textBox3, ... };`

Comment: Do you want to _generate_ names, or _move_ them between the text boxes?

Comment: The problem is to iterate through the array and after i click on generate to increment with one and textBox2 to appear in textBox3 and if i click again to continue this. What i wrote there is how i tried to figure it out but i guess it's incrementing only the numbers of "i" but doesn't do anything with the textboxes. I already have set in the textboxes names by default, i just want to increment them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you just wanna move names between boxes. All you need is a variable to hold the first name.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        var tmp = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
        textBox2.Text = textBox3.Text;
        textBox3.Text = textBox4.Text;
        textBox4.Text = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Works, thank you, I tried this one, but without storing the first textbox and went wrong. Two names were appearing as one name.

Comment: If it's the correct answer please flag it as the answer please